# Missing dependencies in Spyder 4.2.1 (Anaconda 1.10.0)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, jedi

I keep getting the following error message every time I open Spyder:

```
You have missing dependencies!


# Mandatory:
jedi =0.17.2 : None (NOK)

Please install them to avoid this message.

    Note: Spyder could work without some of these dependencies, 
however to have a smooth experience when using Spyder we strongly 
recommend you to install all the listed missing dependencies.



  Failing to install these dependencies might result in bugs. 
Please be sure that any found bugs are not the direct result of 
missing dependencies, prior to reporting a new issue.
```

I have tried to reinstall Anaconda but it didn't solve the problem. I have downloaded this version of Jedi using:

```
pip install jedi==0.17.2
```

in the terminal. When I write:

```
conda list
```

The correct Jedi is shown in the dependencies list. How do I fix this??

Comment: Are you in the correct `virtual environment`?